# Hot Network Question on feed is refreshed too aggressively on Android app

Tags: bug, android-app, hot-questions, android-app-feed

The SE Android app (<s>v1.0.85 beta</s> 1.0.95) refreshes the Hot Network Question (HNQ) on the feed too aggressively.

Steps to reproduce:

1. Open the SE app and wait until it displays the feed with HNQ on the top.
2. Scroll down until the HNQ is hidden, then scroll up to the HNQ without triggering pull-to-refresh.
3. The HNQ changes without actually refreshing the feed.

As far as I can remember, on v1.0.83, the HNQ question would change only when opening the app or do pull-to-refresh.

> [image: HNQ changes without pull-to-refresh]
>
> <sup>GIF animation (2MB) - click to play the animation</sup>

**Note**: Brian just confirmed [it's a bug](https://chat.meta.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/4776022#4776022): "*I've noticed the refresh control unexpectedly appear while scrolling. Could be related.*" Probably there's a better way to make it toggle by itself, just not as abrupt as this

Comment: Sure it's a bug and not by design? Worth asking Brian in chat. (no beta for me, but actually would love the HNQ to toggle by itself)

Comment: @ShadowWizard he just confirmed [it's a bug](http://chat.meta.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/4776022#4776022): "*I've noticed the refresh control unexpectedly appear while scrolling. Could be related.*" Probably there's a better way to make it toggle by itself, just not as abrupt as this.

Comment: Is this bug still exists?